# Apiplatform error 500 -> acces denied for 'document' endpoints

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have an entity named "Document"

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: DocumentRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: [
        "get" => ["security" => "is_granted('ROLE_GUEST')"],
        "post" => ["security" => "is_granted('ROLE_GUEST')"],
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        "get" => ["security" => "is_granted('ROLE_GUEST')"],
        "delete" => ["security" => "is_granted('ROLE_GUEST')"],
        "patch" => ["security" => "is_granted('ROLE_GUEST')"],
    ],
)]
class Document
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Groups(["read:bibliotheque"])]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(["read:bibliotheque"])]
    private ?string $title = null;
```

my security.yml

```yaml
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_USER: ROLE_GUEST
```

i m sure, i have an ROLE_ADMIN account, but, only for Document entity, i cant use any endpoint.

All other entities works perfectly, but for Document, in production (linux) i have an 500 Error Access Denied. (works on dev > windows)
why is not an 403 error ?  and why only for 1 entity ?
"Document" is an reserved word for apiplatform or symfony ?

Comment: I think it has something to do with `firewalls` property in your `security.yaml`. Can you please provide what you have in that property?

Comment: I change name of my entity and it's work.
Nothing with document in my security.yml.

Answer (score 0):

I update my "document" entity name by an other name and it's work perfectly.
I think document is a apipaltform reserved word (like api/docs to watch swagger maybe ?)